# Clearing a filter form removes all data from view

Tags: angularjs

I have a user management view in angular that displays all users in the application in a table. Above that table I have a bunch of input fields that filter through the users. For instance, when you type 'admin' into the username field it will filter the list of users below to only display users with 'admin' in their username.

The filter works fine. But what I'm trying to do is have a button that clears all of the fields and resets the list of users to the complete list.

This snippet displays all users and sets up filter functionality:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{userName: search.userName, lastName: search.lastName, firstName: search.firstName, status: search.status, roles: search.roles}">
   <td>{{user.userName}}</td>
   <td>{{user.firstName + " " + user.lastName}}</td>
   <td><ul><li class="usersearch-rolename" ng-repeat="role in user.roles">{{role.name}}</li></ul></td>
   <td>{{user.emailAddress}}</td>
   <td>{{user.status}}</td>
   <td><a class="yellow edit" href="#" ng-click="getUserId(user)"><span class="round-icon"><span class="border"></span><img src="/images/icons/icon_edit.png" alt="edit" class="icon"></span></a><br /></td>
</tr>
```

And here's a sample input field used to filter one of the user properties:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="user-search-label" for="id_loginid">Username</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Login ID" name="login_id" id="id_loginid" class="user-search-input" ng-model="$parent.$parent.search.id">
</div
```

And my clear fields function that successfully clears all fields, but also removes all the users from displaying on the page:

```
scope.clearFields = function() {
    scope.search.userName = null;
    scope.search.lastName = null;
    scope.search.city = null;
    scope.search.state = null;
    scope.search.zip = null;
    scope.search.roles = null;
    scope.search.firstName = null;
    scope.search.phone = null;
    scope.search.status = null;
    console.log(scope.users);
};
```

And I added the console.log at the end to prove that `scope.users` still holds all users after the clearFields function is executed -- so the data is indeed there.

Comment: Can you set up an SSCCE on jsfiddle or something?  I'm thinking you may want to do `scope.search = {}` instead though.

Comment: That worked! Put this in an answer and I'll accept. Would you mind explaining why that works? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of clearing each field value individually, use `scope.search = {}`.

Otherwise you will have an object that looks like `{userName: null, lastName: null}`, etc.  The filter will try to compare each property and if `data.userName != null`, it's not satisfied.  If the property is not there, no comparison is done.